# How to rotate hand object with accelerometer data using `rgl` and `animation`

Tags: r, animation, accelerometer, rgl

Let's say I had a wireframe, 3D object such as https://free3d.com/3d-model/freerealsichand-85561.html

Let's say I wanted to fix the wrist of said object to be the readout of an accelerometer wrist watch (e.g., get position via dead-reckoning).

How can I plot a 3-D image like this in `rgl`?

How can I rotate / translate said image based on changes to accelerometer data?

Bonus for:  how can I play an `animation` of this activity.  (e.g., library `animation`)

The accelerometer is 3-DOF:  x-acc, y-acc, z-acc without any other data.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That link includes the hand in several formats, but `rgl` can't currently read them.  It comes closest with the .OBJ format, but can't read the normals or textures that are recorded in that file, so it fails.  You might want to try updating `readOBJ` to support more of the OBJ format; alternatively, you can remove that information like this:

```
hand <- readLines("hand.OBJ")
poly <- grepl("^f ", hand)
hand[poly] <- gsub("/[^ ]+", "", hand[poly])
handmesh <- readOBJ(textConnection(hand))
```

This will give some warnings because it ignores some other parts of that file, but it results in an object that `rgl` can handle.  You can plot it like this:

```
shade3d(handmesh, col = "pink")
```

To translate and rotate the shape, use the `translate3d` and `rotate3d` functions on the `userMatrix`  e.g.

```
par3d(userMatrix = rotate3d(par3d("userMatrix"), 0.1, 1,0,0))
```

to rotate the hand by 0.1 radians around the x axis.  (You could also rotate the `handmesh` itself if you want a permanent change.)

You'll need to spend some time figuring out what are the coordinates of the wrist, and translating your 3-DOF data into the right coordinate system.

You don't need `animation` for an animation; see the examples in `?rgl::play3d`.  For example, to spin the hand around the x axis, you could use

```
open3d()
shade3d(handmesh, col = "pink")
play3d(spin3d(axis = c(1, 0, 0)))
```

Comment: Thanks for the information.  I have enough to work with to solve my needs.  Very helpful examples.

Answer (score 0):

Based on the answer @user2554330 provided, I dug into the details.

rgl::readOBJ is a bit imperfect, and I notified R-forge:rgl of this matter:  https://r-forge.r-project.org/tracker/index.php?func=detail&aid=6543&group_id=234&atid=949

```
# rgl::readOBJ
beginT = Sys.time();
hand <- readLines("hand.OBJ")
poly <- grepl("^f ", hand)
hand[poly] <- gsub("/[^ ]+", "", hand[poly])
handmesh <- readOBJ(textConnection(hand))
endT = Sys.time(); print(endT-beginT);
# Time difference of 1.555696964263916 secs
```

My hack has four functions:

```
#' Convert String Matrix to Numeric Matrix
#'
#' @param m string matrix
#'
#' @return numeric matrix
#' @export

numericMatrix = function(m)
{

  m = as.matrix(m);
  mdim = dim(m);

  nm <- mapply(m, FUN=as.numeric);
  matrix(data=nm, nrow=mdim[1], ncol=mdim[2])

}


#' Convert String List of "f" to numeric multi-dimensional array
#'
#' @param fobj 
#'
#' @return fn, multidimension array of rows, cols, and values
#' @export
#'

numericF = function(fobj)
{

  rdim = dim(fobj)[1];  # rows
  cdim = dim(fobj)[2];  # cols
  ddim = 3;

  fn = array(NA,dim=c(rdim,cdim,ddim));


  for(rn in 1:rdim)
    {
    for(cn in 1:cdim)
      {
      rcdat = fobj[rn,cn];
      fdat = as.numeric(unlist(strsplit(rcdat,"/",fixed=T))); # basic numeric case
      fn[rn,cn,] = fdat;
      }
    }



  #fn[1:10,1:4,1:3]

  fn;


    }



#' Internally equivalent to rgl 'readOBJ'
#'
#' @param rawobj Raw object read in using parseFileOBJ
#' 
#' rgl::readOBJ
#' hand <- readLines("hand.OBJ")
#' poly <- grepl("^f ", hand)
#' hand[poly] <- gsub("/[^ ]+", "", hand[poly])
#' handmesh <- readOBJ(textConnection(hand))
#' 
#' mymesh = buildBasicMeshFromOBJ(parseFileOBJ("hand.OBJ"));
#' 
#' These appear to be equivalent in the basic form
#'
#' @return list object equivalent to readOBJ output
#' @export
#'

buildBasicMeshFromOBJ <- function(rawobj)
{

  mesh = list();
      vb = as.matrix(rawobj$v);
      vb = cbind(vb,1);
    mesh$vb = t(vb);
    mesh$it = matrix(0,nrow=3,ncol=0);
    mesh$primitivetype = "triangle";
    mesh$ib = t(as.matrix(rawobj$fn[,,1]));

    attr(mesh,"class") = c("mesh3d","shape3d");

  mesh;  
}

#' Parse file of type OBJ
#'
#' Specification for OBJ format can be found here:
#' http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec
#' 
#' Requires gdata::trim
#' 
#' @param filename 
#'
#' @return list 'rawobj' with all details from the file
#' @export
#'
#' @examples
#' rawobj = parseFileOBJ("hand.obj");
parseFileOBJ <- function(filename)
{



  linestxt <- readLines(filename)                 # read all lines
  linestxt = gsub("\\s+"," ",gdata::trim(linestxt));  # replace multiple spaces with single space
  linesobj = strsplit(linestxt," ",fixed=T);      # split on spaces


  rawobj = list();
  rawobj$lines = c();
  rawobj$comments = c();



  for(i in 1:length(linesobj))
  {
    hir = gdata::trim(linesobj[[i]]);
    key = hir[1]; 
    rdat = hir[-1]; 
    rlen = length(rdat);
    rstr = paste(rdat,collapse=" ");
    if (key=="#") {
      rawobj$lines = c(rawobj$lines,"comments");
      rawobj$comments = c(rawobj$comments,rstr);
      } else { rawobj$lines = c(rawobj$lines,key); 
              if(is.null(rawobj[[key]])) { rawobj[[key]] = rdat; } else 
                {  rawobj[[key]] = rbind(rawobj[[key]],rdat);}
      }
  }


  if(!is.null(rawobj[["v"]])) { rawobj[["v"]] = numericMatrix(rawobj[["v"]]);  }
  if(!is.null(rawobj[["vn"]])) { rawobj[["vn"]] = numericMatrix(rawobj[["vn"]]);  }
  if(!is.null(rawobj[["vt"]])) { rawobj[["vt"]] = numericMatrix(rawobj[["vt"]]);  }

  # "f" could be numeric (f 1 2 3 4) or (f -4 -3 -2 -1) or references to v,vn,vt (f 1/1/1 2/2/2 3/3/3 4/4/4) or (f v/vt/vn v/vt/vn v/vt/vn v/vt/vn) or (f 1//1 2//2 3//3 4//4)
  # rdat = c("1102/9904/4404","2981/9909/4404","3943/9910/4404","2854/9905/4404");
  # rdat = c('1//1','2//2','3//3',4//4');

  if(!is.null(rawobj[["f"]])) { rawobj[["fn"]] = numericF(rawobj[["f"]]);  }



  rawobj;

}
```

Basic usage:

```
# Takes longer, but processes "all" info in the file
beginT = Sys.time();
rawobj = parseFileOBJ("hand.OBJ");
endT = Sys.time(); print(endT-beginT); beginT = endT;
# Time difference of 6.9523830413818359 secs
mymesh = buildBasicMeshFromOBJ(rawobj);
endT = Sys.time(); print(endT-beginT);
# Time difference of 0.0030009746551513672 secs
```

The rawobject has **all** the information found in the OBJ file per this specification:  http://www.martinreddy.net/gfx/3d/OBJ.spec